# How to setup a shared calendar for two people?

Tags: google-calendar

I am thinking of using Gmail and from there using the Google Calendar so that I and another colleague can collaborate and know what are we up to.

Can you advise how to go about setting up a shared calendar using Gmail that also synchronizes across iPhone device?

And whether the synchronization is both ways or only web to iPhone ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple! Create a calendar, share it. It will be available on the iphone - with either way synchronization that you can control